# unable to runt the command pip3 which always says error from 2.7

Tags: python3, pip

When I run

```
#pip3
```

command I received below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 6, in <module>
    import compileall
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> what I tried to resolve ?

Step 1 - Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
```

Step 2 - Delete the directory

```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

Step 3 - Reinstall pip3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

When i run pip3 command i still get the same error mentioned above.

Much appreciated the help?.

## Note Ubuntu Version:

> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
>
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
>
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
>
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"

Comment: Do you have PYTHONPATH set somewhere?

Comment: What do you get with `python -V; python3 -V`.  Most issues I've seen relate to users changing their default python versions... I'd also check your system is fully-upgraded; as 16.04.5 implies you've not fully-upgraded since before 2019-Mar-01 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) as your system should have reported 16.04.6 which could also be your problem too.

Comment: If you have PYTHONPATH set somewhere, you need to unset it or comment it out and then source the file. For example, if you have it set in `~/.bashrc` comment out the line with the PYTHONPATH and then run `. ~/.bashrc` to source the file and then run `export PYTHONPATH=''` for good measure. Let me know if you have it set and I will make this an answer.

Comment: To see if it is set, run: `echo $PYTHONPATH` and it should return nothing. If you get response, follow my previous comment to unset it.

Comment: thanks @mchid. rocking. I used PYTHONPATH set in the .bashrc to 2.7 version. Also, i removed all the ros related packages. now i am able to see the output below pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5). thanks for your wonderful reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens sometimes when `PYTHONPATH` is set somewhere.

To see if it is set run the following command:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

If the command returns a path, you need to unset `PYTHONPATH`.

If you have it set in `~/.bashrc` comment out the line for `PYTHONPATH` and then run:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

to source the file and then run:

```
export PYTHONPATH=''
```

for good measure.

[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789409/why-does-python35-import-try-to-load-python27-package#comment63053614_37789409) and [Reference2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5430)

Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48003998).

Comment: I was about to ask you to keep the separate post so that i can thumbs  up. ;)